Skype failing on out of the box Ubuntu install
I have done a fresh install of the latest Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS onto a 2nd hand HP laptop.  One of the first things I installed was Skype using the Ubuntu Software Center.  Running it using the launcher causes it to start, and it accepts a username and password with validation with the Skype servers.  Once you enter the password the screen goes blank and remains that way for over an hour.
Running skype on the command line results in the same behaviour, with the below output, all but the final line was produced prior to the username/password entry.
What can I do to fix this problem?
username@username-HP:~$ skype
+ [ -f /home/username/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/settings.json ]
+ export SKYPE_LOGS=/home/username/snap/skype/361/logs
+ [ ! -d /home/username/snap/skype/361/logs ]
+ exec /snap/skype/361/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux

(skypeforlinux:53137): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:27:02.692: Theme parsing
error: gtk.css:1422:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(skypeforlinux:53137): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:27:02.696: Theme parsing
error: gtk.css:3308:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(skypeforlinux:53137): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:27:02.697: Theme parsing
error: gtk.css:3770:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
[53137:0922/152702.815723:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call
method: org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit: object_path=
/org/freedesktop/login1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An
AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this
recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.500" (uid=1000 pid=53137
comm="/snap/skype/361/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli"
label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)")
interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="Inhibit" error
name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1"
(uid=0 pid=1043 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind" label="unconfined")
[53137:0922/152702.816980:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call
method: org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit: object_path=
/org/freedesktop/login1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An
AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this
recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.500" (uid=1000 pid=53137
comm="/snap/skype/361/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli"
label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)")
interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="Inhibit" error
name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1"
(uid=0 pid=1043 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind" label="unconfined")
[53137:0922/152707.831203:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call
method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path=
/org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported:
This method is not part of the idle inhibition specification:
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/latest/
[53137:0922/152707.832151:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call
method: org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /:
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents
this sender from sending this message to this recipient;
type="method_call", sender=":1.574" (uid=1000 pid=53137
comm="/snap/skype/361/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli"
label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)") interface="org.gnome.ScreenSaver"
member="GetActive" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
destination="org.gnome.ScreenSaver" (uid=1000 pid=2777
comm="/usr/bin/gjs -m /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.S"
label="unconfined")
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored
credentials fetched from keytar.
     at
/snap/skype/361/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:582534
     at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:551
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored
credentials fetched from keytar.
     at
/snap/skype/361/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:582534
     at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:551
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored
credentials fetched from keytar.
     at
/snap/skype/361/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:582534
     at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:551
######
# un/pw entered in gui here
######
[53137:0922/152734.283606:ERROR:quota_database.cc(836)] Could not open
the quota database, resetting.



I have rather embarrassingly found the answer on the Microsoft Site; turn it off and on again.
As reported there on second boot I got a keychain unlock popup and Skype functioned normally.

Wow!  chance of one in a million where that actually works.  Glad it did. Be sure to mark your answer as "Accepted."
